Measure rigidity for higher-rank subgroup actions on homogeneous space
Let $G$ be a semisimple Lie group, $\Gamma$ a lattice in $G$, and $H$ a higher-rank subgroup of $G$ (e.g., a non-split Cartan subgroup). Let $\mu$ be an $H$-invariant and ergodic probability measure on the homogeneous space $G/\Gamma$. Under what conditions on $G$, $\Gamma$, and $H$ can one prove that $\mu$ is algebraic, i.e., it is the $L$-invariant measure on a single closed $L$-orbit for some closed subgroup $L \geq H$?

This is the main result of https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.05133.

NB above the arXiv reference links to Joinings of higher rank torus actions on homogeneous spaces by Manfred Einsiedler, Elon Lindenstrauss (arXiv 2015, Publ. IHES 2019).

The above mentioned theorem applies only to joinings. The most general theorem (currently written) is for maximal Cartan actions, in the low entropy paper of Einsiedler-Lindenstruass - https://www.aimsciences.org/article/doi/10.3934/jmd.2008.2.83 . Elon and Manfred recently released their long announced paper - https://arxiv.org/abs/2307.04163 which deals with non maximal actions, but only for forms of $SL_{2}$, as the paper uses Elon's commutation trick in section 6 (the same one from the QUE papers). The general techniques in the papers (quantitative recurrence) do generalize though...
